# R prediction interval - two different methods get two different values

Tags: r, ggplot2, predictive-models

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to get a prediction interval for a linear model using the mtcars dataset. I try two different methods and get two different answers. I'm all turned around and I don't know which one is correct.

On the one hand, I'm using the standard error equation to find the standard error of the line. I then create a geom_abline and either add or subtract the standard error  to or from the intercept value.

```
mtcars <- mtcars 

r <- cor(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$wt)

# equation for standard error value 

standard_error_of_line <- sqrt ( ( ( 1 - (r ^ 2) ) * sum(((mtcars$mpg) - mean(mtcars$mpg)) ^ 2) )/ (length(mtcars$mpg) - 2) )

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm', color = 'blue', se = TRUE) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 37.2851 + standard_error_of_line, slope = -5.3445, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 37.2851 - standard_error_of_line, slope = -5.3445, linetype = 'dashed')
```

[image]

I also tried creating a linear model and then using the predict function with the interval argument set to "prediction". I then attached the columns and fortified the mtcars dataframe with the new variables and used the geom_line layer of ggplot2.

```
mtcars_lm_mpg_wt <- lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars) 

mtcars_lm_mpg_wt_prediction_interval <- predict(mtcars_lm_mpg_wt, interval = "prediction")

mtcars <- cbind(mtcars, mtcars_lm_mpg_wt_prediction_interval)

ggplot(data = new_df, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm', color = 'blue', se = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(y = lwr), linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_line(aes( y =upr), linetype = "dashed")
```

But this graph has a wider prediction interval. Did I do something wrong in the first or second case? Or is there something I'm not understanding in the theory?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible the gray band is a confidence interval and the dashed band is a prediction interval?

Comment: Right the grey band is the confidence interval and the dashed band is the prediction interval- I’m trying to figure out why the prediction interval is different in the top method vs the bottom method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are missing the test statistic when calculating the margin of error in your first example.

Recall the general formula :

[image]

Since n=32 records, you will have 30 df. I'll assume a significance level = 0.05.

Try:

```
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'lm', color = 'blue', se = TRUE) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 37.2851 + qt(0.975, 30)*standard_error_of_line, slope = -5.3445, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_abline(intercept = 37.2851 - qt(0.975, 30)*standard_error_of_line, slope = -5.3445, linetype = 'dashed')
```

Comment: I see I took the se by itself instead of this number times the standard error - qt is like how many standard errors on the t distribution I think?

Comment: In this example, qt() allows you to find the 97.5th quantile of the T-distribution with 30 degrees of freedom.